# Technique for generating valid type names with generic in Roslyn

Tags: c#, reflection, code-generation, roslyn

I'm trying out a few possible techniques for generating a dynamic proxy of a C# interface at runtime. So far I've found Roslyn has taken me a fair away without too much friction, but I'm a bit stuck on dealing with generic types. In particular, getting type names to parse.

My basic workflow is:

- Build the scaffolding for usings, a namespace and a class as a `CompilationUnitSyntax`
- Inspect the interface getting proxied
- For every method on the interface, use the `MethodInfo` to build a `MethodDeclarationSyntax` using `SyntaxFactory.MethodDeclaration`, with the goal to my new dynamic class

Here's an example of the issue I'm puzzling over. At this point it seems that I need to parse a string to get a `TypeSyntax` (in this case for the return type), and the only place I can take it is from `methodInfo.ReturnType.Name`:

`var methodDecl = SyntaxFactory.MethodDeclaration(SyntaxFactory.ParseTypeName(methodInfo.ReturnType.Name), methodInfo.Name);`

The problem is `SyntaxFactory.ParseTypeName` is expecting 'valid' C# syntax type declarations, for example `List<string>`, but accessing the Name or FullName properties are in the form:

```
{Name = "List`1" FullName =
"System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[UnitTests.SamplePoco, UnitTests,
Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]"}   System.Type
{System.RuntimeType}
```

which obviously won't parse, with the backticks, lack of angle brackets etc.

Is there a better bridge between Reflection style classes (MethodInfo, Types) and Roslyn syntax units? I'm also trying out a pure reflection emit style solution as well, but wanted to see if I could get a Roslyn based one going here.

Comment: You can recursively expand `GetGenericTypeArguments()` instead of parsing the string.

Comment: I don't quite see how this approach can bridge this gap, maybe I'm missing something. This path seems like it can only ever return Type objects, which is what I already have. All of the overloads of the Roslyn function SyntaxFactory.MethodDeclaration() (which is what I am calling) expect an instance of TypeSyntax. That seems to be the fundamental hurdle to overcome.

Comment: Yes; you'd still need to write code to format it as a C#-style typename.

Comment: Roslyn has code that does this, but it looks like it's all internal. http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/MetadataReader/MetadataHelpers.cs,62

Answer (score 7):

I created this extension method to address the issue.

```
static class SyntaxExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Generates the type syntax.
    /// </summary>
    public static TypeSyntax AsTypeSyntax( this Type type )
    {
        string name = type.Name.Replace( '+', '.' );

        if ( type.IsGenericType ) {
            // Get the C# representation of the generic type minus its type arguments.
            name = name.Substring( 0, name.IndexOf( "`" ) );

            // Generate the name of the generic type.
            var genericArgs = type.GetGenericArguments();
            return SyntaxFactory.GenericName( SyntaxFactory.Identifier( name ),
                SyntaxFactory.TypeArgumentList( SyntaxFactory.SeparatedList( genericArgs.Select( AsTypeSyntax ) ) )
            );
        } else
            return SyntaxFactory.ParseTypeName( name );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to create a TypeSyntax from a generic type, then this static factory class might help.  You will need to get the list of generic arguments for types you wish to generate, but the factory I post at the bottom (also available in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/frankbryce/a4ee2bf799ab3878ae91)) helped me get instances of `TypeSyntax` relatively painlessly.

Example of how to use it:

```
// List<Dictionary<string, List<Type>>>
TypeSyntaxFactory.GetTypeSyntax(
    "List",
    TypeSyntaxFactory.GetTypeSyntax(
        "Dictionary",
        TypeSyntaxFactory.GetTypeSyntax(
            "string"
        ),
        TypeSyntaxFactory.GetTypeSyntax(
            "List",
            "Type"
        )
    )
)
```

I'm not sure what the best way would be to deal with the output from reflection, but you could probably just take the substring of the type identifier before the "`" symbol.  In my IDE, this symbol isn't a valid character for type names, so it should be safe to assume that it is part of the reflection type output.

Finally, here is the copy of this [gist](https://gist.github.com/frankbryce/a4ee2bf799ab3878ae91)

```
public static class TypeSyntaxFactory
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Used to generate a type without generic arguments
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="identifier">The name of the type to be generated</param>
    /// <returns>An instance of TypeSyntax from the Roslyn Model</returns>
    public static TypeSyntax GetTypeSyntax(string identifier)
    {
        return
            SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName(
                SyntaxFactory.Identifier(identifier)
            );
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Used to generate a type with generic arguments
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="identifier">Name of the Generic Type</param>
    /// <param name="arguments">
    /// Types of the Generic Arguments, which must be basic identifiers
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>An instance of TypeSyntax from the Roslyn Model</returns>
    public static TypeSyntax GetTypeSyntax(string identifier, params string[] arguments)
    {
        return GetTypeSyntax(identifier, arguments.Select(GetTypeSyntax).ToArray());
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Used to generate a type with generic arguments
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="identifier">Name of the Generic Type</param>
    /// <param name="arguments">
    /// Types of the Generic Arguments, which themselves may be generic types
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>An instance of TypeSyntax from the Roslyn Model</returns>
    public static TypeSyntax GetTypeSyntax(string identifier, params TypeSyntax[] arguments)
    {
        return
            SyntaxFactory.GenericName(
                SyntaxFactory.Identifier(identifier),
                SyntaxFactory.TypeArgumentList(
                    SyntaxFactory.SeparatedList(
                        arguments.Select(
                            x =>
                            {
                                if(x is GenericNameSyntax)
                                {
                                    var gen_x = x as GenericNameSyntax;
                                    return
                                        GetTypeSyntax(
                                            gen_x.Identifier.ToString(),
                                            gen_x.TypeArgumentList.Arguments.ToArray()
                                        );
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    return x;
                                }
                            }
                        )
                    )
                )
            );
    }
}
```